# node.js "Connection reset by peer" when client in same process as server

Tags: node.js

I am just beginning a node.js project and am at the stage where I am writing my first unit tests.

In the unit test I start up a server then I create a client and send a request to the server.  I will be doing an assert on the response.

Now, if I do this using two separate js files, one for starting the server, the other for the client, and I run them in separate node instances, it works fine.  The server starts up, I run the other js and the client makes the request successfully.

However, if I put the same code into a single js and run it within a single node instance, I get "Connection reset by peer" error when the client tries to connect.  I tried using a setTimeout to delay the request for a few seconds after the server started, and I tried catching the error on the socket.  Neither approach seems to help.

I would really like to be able to run this as a single process.  It makes writing and managing the unit tests so much easier.  Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks
Martin

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.2.6/api.html#server-listen-164)

> server.listen(port, [hostname],
>   [callback]) Begin accepting
>   connections on the specified port and
>   hostname. If the hostname is omitted,
>   the server will accept connections
>   directed to any IPv4 address
>   (INADDR_ANY).
>
> To listen to a unix socket, supply a
>   filename instead of port and hostname.
>
> This function is asynchronous. The
>   last parameter callback will be called
>   when the server has been bound to the
>   port.
>
> server.listen(path, [callback])

I think you should do your unit test from inside the `callback`?

At least it worked for me. I am using [express.js](http://expressjs.com/) because it is awesome. I also am using [wwwdude](https://github.com/pfleidi/node-wwwdude) to make http request, but the following snippet does work for me:

```
const PORT = 1234;
const HOST = 'localhost';

const assert = require('assert');
const wwwdude = require('wwwdude');
const express = require('express');
const app = module.exports = express.createServer();
const client = wwwdude.createClient({
    headers: { 'User-Agent': 'wwwdude test 42' },
});

app.use(
    express.staticProvider(__dirname + '/public')
);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello World!');
});

if (!module.parent) {
    app.listen(PORT, HOST, function() {
        client.get('http://localhost:1234')
        .addListener('error', function (err) {
        }).addListener('success', function (data, resp) {
            assert.equal('Hello World!', data);
            process.exit();
        }).send();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  But, I'm not sure how it answers my question.  I can't see anything in the documentation that says that you need to do anything special if you're connecting to a server from a client in the same process.  Maybe I'm just slow, could you spell it out for me?

Comment: I was on holiday, but the quote is "This function is asynchronous. The last parameter callback will be called when the server has been bound."? You should look for it in the documentation?